# Background Fetch, NSURLSession GET and local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I need to develop an app that could detect if its connected to a certain Access Point. To make sure it is connected to my AP, I need to do an HTTP GET in the background and when the authentication is fetched, notify (local notif.) the user. Can I implement this using NSURLSession running in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here is an example:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                         completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         // ... Do notification
     }];

 [task resume];
```

Comment: According to the Apple Docs, "because data tasks do not store the data to a file, they are not supported in background sessions".

Comment: Thanks; Then do a download task!